I am trying to make a parsing tree using python, The issue I am facing is that the tree is horizontally, I want it to be vertically
I have created a program that basically does a parsing tree calculation. I have completed the code but my only issue that I cant seem to fix is the shape of the tree output I want the tree to look like this
                  *
                 /  \
                3    4

Instead its looking like this tree right here
enter image description here
class BinOp(Node):
    def __init__(self, left, operator, right):
        self.left = left
        self.operator = operator
        self.right = right

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.operator}"

    def print_tree(self, indent=0, position='root'):
        lines = []
        # Print right child first
        right = self.right.print_tree(indent + 1, 'right')
        lines.extend(right)

        # Print own value
        prefix = ' ' * (indent * 4)
        if position == 'right':
            lines.append(f"{prefix}┌── {self}")
        elif position == 'left':
            lines.append(f"{prefix}└── {self}")
        else:  # Root node has no arrow
            lines.append(f"{prefix}{self}")

        # Print left child
        left = self.left.print_tree(indent + 1, 'left')
        lines.extend(left)

        return lines

    def evaluate(self):
        left_val = self.left.evaluate()
        right_val = self.right.evaluate()
        if self.operator == '+':
            return left_val + right_val
        elif self.operator == '-':
            return left_val - right_val
        elif self.operator == '*':
            return left_val * right_val
        elif self.operator == '/':
            if right_val == 0:
                raise ValueError("Division by zero")
            return left_val / right_val
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid operator")

class Num(Node):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = int(value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def print_tree(self, indent=0, position='root'):
        prefix = ' ' * (indent * 4)
        if position == 'right':
            return [f"{prefix}┌── {self.value}"]
        elif position == 'left':
            return [f"{prefix}└── {self.value}"]
        else:
            return [f"{prefix}{self.value}"]


I have tried to switch the signs I have included in my file, but that didn't work. I have also saw an example on google but that made me run into a bunch of errors, can anyone please help me fix this?

There are several Q&A on this. Like this one or this one... Do none of them answer your question?

@trincot it really doesnt because my input is from a different file

What do you mean with "file" here? There is no file operation in your program, and the structure you create consists of BinOps instances, which map very well to the node structures used in those linked answers.

Care to explain what you mean with "my input is from a different file"? How does that affect the ability to work with the nodes you have created?
